# How should we handle "How much does ______ cost?" questions?

Tags: discussion, scope

Every aviation site eventually gets "the money questions" -- We already have a few of these:

- [How much, generally speaking, does it cost to learn how to fly?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/627/how-much-generally-speaking-does-it-cost-to-learn-how-to-fly)
- [How much should it cost to get IFR-rated? What to look for?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/691/how-much-should-it-cost-to-get-ifr-rated-what-to-look-for)
- [What does it cost to get an ATP certificate from scratch?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1255/what-does-it-cost-to-get-an-atp-certificate-from-scratch)
- [What are the typical facets of ownership costs, for a single engine aircraft?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/77/what-are-the-typical-facets-of-ownership-costs-for-a-single-engine-aircraft)

so I think it's time to ask the tough internal question: How do we want to handle them?

Answer (score 4):

My two cents:

**Questions that ask for nothing more than a cost estimate should be considered off-topic.**
It's really hard to answer cost questions generally -- costs vary from country to country, and they can even vary substantially within a country or even within the same city (particularly true of training costs, where frequency of training can be a huge factor).

A few of them (like the three "How much should it cost to get *some rating*." questions) are going to keep getting asked, so they should probably be edited to be generic and have a canonical answer posted that lists the requirements and some sample calculations with assumed numbers (like [pondlife's answer on the first one](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/633/64)). They can then be used as duplicate targets for similar questions about the same rating.
(Ideally I think we should build these in layers - a good answer for Private, then Instrument refers back to Private, Commercial refers back to Private and Instrument. ATP refers back to Commercial, Private & Instrument - so someone can follow the whole chain and we don't need to update a bunch of answers if the requirements for a Private certificate changes.)

---

**Questions that ask for cost *factors* may be on-topic.**
Similar to the logic for canonicalizing a few of the "How much should it cost" questions, we can list factors (and give example numbers) - these run the risk of becoming "List of Things" answers, but I think we can avoid that with judicious voting and editing...

Comment: Do you think we need a custom close reason for "money" reasons, or does "too broad" and "primarily opinion-based" convey the message sufficiently?

Comment: I think this is a good general approach, cost questions are definitely of interest to a lot of people and it would be difficult to ignore them completely. But we should limit answers to costs that can be estimated with 'standard' assumptions, like ratings; things like the price of avgas or second-hand aircraft should definitely be OT and as you said,  good responses from the community should handle that anyway.

Comment: Putting a dollar value on a student's training is always an exercise in guesswork anyway.  No two students start from the same place in background knowledge, ability to learn, and so on.

Comment: I agree that cost factors may be on topic. I know when I was looking at owning an airplane, it wasn't specific numbers I was looking for, but an idea of what all I might have to pay for.